# ImportError: No module named markdown_preview_lib.pygments.lexers._asy_builtins

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to use Markdown Preview.
Since 2 weeks ago or so it stopped working.
It used to work, I am not sure exactly when it stopped loading the plugin.
When I open the package control, I no longer see Markdown Preview as an option. However I cannot download it either, because it is in face already installed. When I reload sublime, it tries to reload this plugin, and fails to do so with the below error.

I have tried to change the python interpreter, but was recommended not to for sublime text 2.
I did try regardless - it has not changed anything.

Here is the sublime interpreter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 62, in reload_plugin
  File "./markdown_wrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
    __import__("lib.markdown_preview_lib.pygments.%s.%s" % (parent, mod[:-3]))
ImportError: No module named markdown_preview_lib.pygments.lexers._asy_builtins
```

Here is the actual code in the Markdown Preview packages.

```
import sys
import os
# We have to modify the path, we've at least pushed the library
# down into a unique enough package that we shouldn't match anyone else
pygment_path = os.path.join(sublime.packages_path(), "Markdown Preview", "lib")
if pygment_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(pygment_path)
# In the sublime environment, there just appears to be no other way.
# Loop through and import the submodules so we can find them later
for parent in ("lexers", "styles"):
    parent_folder = os.path.join(pygment_path, "markdown_preview_lib", "pygments", parent)
    for mod in os.listdir(parent_folder):
        if mod.endswith(".py") and mod != "__init__.py":
            __import__("lib.markdown_preview_lib.pygments.%s.%s" % (parent, mod[:-3]))
            # importlib.import_module(pygments)
```

I have double checked the directories and they are correct - the current working directory is `Users/name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Markdown Preview`.

`_asy_builtins` is in `Users/name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Markdown Preview/lib/mardown_preview_lib.pygments/`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please describe "stopped working". What were you doing when the error occurred? Does it happen every time you use Sublime, or just some times? What is the effect of the error - can you not preview Markdown files at all? Does completely quitting and restarting Sublime (using `⌘-Q`, not just clicking the red button on the window) do anything? Please [edit] your question to include as many details as possible.

Comment: It has not been working for sometime - so it doesn't work at all any more. I can no longer see the installed package when I open the package control, thus not able to activate the plugin. And restarting Sublime does not make a difference.